# Android Studio how to use multiple appBarConfiguration? One for drawer layout and one for bottom navigation view

Tags: java, android, navigation

I need to use Drawerlayout and BottomNavigationView in the same activity. This is my Activity [HomeActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcmLP.png)

The DrawerLayout works perfectly, but the BottomNavigationView does not use the AppBarConfiguration that is defined, but that of the DrawerLayout and when interacting with the BottomNavigationView it works, but showing me the fragments established in the AppBarConfiguration of the DrawerLayout.

I'm using Java.

Comment: Please provide sourcecode as text inside of your question. Checkout [formatting-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) for this.

Comment: I can't modify ... or I don't know how to do it :|

Comment: `AppBarConfiguration` only applies to the app bar, it wouldn't apply to `BottomNavigationView`. What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: I need to use DrawerLayout and BottomNavigationView in the same activity